# Convert Java Method to Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, converters

I am trying to convert the following function into Objective-C:

```
private static byte[] convertByteArray(int p_int) {
         byte[] l_byte_array = new byte[4];
         int MASK_c = 0xFF;
         for (short i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                l_byte_array[i] = (byte) ((p_int >> (8 * i)) & MASK_c);
         }
         return l_byte_array;
   }
```

I already tried:

```
-(char *)convertByteArray:(int)p_int
{
    const char *l_byte_array[4];
    int MASK_c = 0xFF;
    for (short i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        l_byte_array[i] = (char *) ((p_int >> (8 * i)) & MASK_c);
    }
    return l_byte_array;
}
```

But thats not correct I guess...

Update:

If I try without the const:

```
-(char *)convertByteArray:(int)p_int
{
    char *l_byte_array[4];
    int MASK_c = 0xFF;
    for (short i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        l_byte_array[i] = (char *) ((p_int >> (8 * i)) & MASK_c);
    }
    return l_byte_array;
}
```

I get two warnings with my Return Statement:

1. address of stack memory associated with local variable '' returned
2. incompatible pointer types returning char[4] * from a function with result type char *

Comment: I'd suggest adding the reason why you believe it to not be correct, such as errors, or a comparative output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> address of stack memory associated with local variable '' returned

You cannot return a pointer to a local variable of your function, because the pointer
will be invalid as soon as the function returns.
The solution is to *allocate* memory for the byte array and return that.

> incompatible pointer types returning char[4] * from a function with
>   result type char *

`char *l_byte_array[4]` is an array of 4 *pointers* to `char`, not an array of 4 `char`.

A working solution is

```
-(char *)convertByteArray:(int)p_int
{
    char *l_byte_array = malloc(4);
    int MASK_c = 0xFF;
    for (short i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        l_byte_array[i] = (char) ((p_int >> (8 * i)) & MASK_c);
    }
    return l_byte_array;
}
```

Note that the caller of that method has to `free()` the memory when it is no longer needed:

```
char *byte_array = [self convertByteArray:some_int];
// … do something with the byte array ...
free(byte_array);
```

Note also that right-shifting a *negative number* is implementation-dependent,
so you might consider to use an `unsigned int` parameter instead.

Comment: But where to free the memory?! After Return Statement? Cause char *l_byte_array is not global...

Comment: @chrizstone: The *calling function* has to free the memory. I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: @chrizstone: You are welcome. - You might also look into alternative solutions which are not direct translations of the Java code. For example, returning `NSData` as an Objective-C wrapper for the byte array.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with these two lines in the corresponding versions.

Java:

```
byte[] l_byte_array = new byte[4];
```

Objective-C

```
const char *l_byte_array[4];
```

I believe `const` means you cannot edit the object after it's declared, which implies that your for-loop will not work as expected.  Remove `const` and see what happens.

Regarding your errors:

```
 1. address of stack memory associated with local variable '' returned
 2. incompatible pointer types returning char[4] * from a function with result type char *
```

1. Your variable is local, so when the method ends the variable will be freed from the stack. Perhaps set a global variable so you don't lose the data, or don't pass a pointer.
2. Apparently the variable you're using to capture the return is not declared properly.  Hopefully fixing issue #1 will fix this issue also.  Make sure the declarations are the same, or that you can at least cast the object to the appropriate type.

Comment: `const` is checked by the compiler. Either it compiles or not, but you will not get "unexpected results".